# KeyPress method does not work due to no reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

There are several KeyPress method in my code. All are working except the one due to no reference. I have checked the project for naming mistake. But there is no any mistake. How can I make reference for this method.

[image]

btnback_KeyPress is not working.

Comment: WPF, Winforms, asp.net?

Comment: This is Winforms code.

Comment: And how are you hooking up the event? It's not *just* done on naming conventions - you do need to explicitly hook it up, it's just that when you create an event, VS created the (awful, IMO) name for you...

Comment: I have done the same the thing for all KeyPress. All are working except the btnback_KeyPress.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you just don't have the event hooked up. Go into the designer, select the `btnback` button, then in the Events tab of the Properties window, find the `KeyPress` event and subscribe the `btnback_KeyPress` method to it as a handler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wire the event to the button.

You can do so by selecting your button in the `[Design]` view and then selecting the Events tab (circled in red) from the properties view.

At `KeyPress`, enter your event name.

[image: Wiring up an event]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a line of code in the Form1.Designer (supposedly it's Form1). Look it up and add

```
this.btnback.KeyPress += new System.EventHandler(this.btnback_KeyPress);
```

Comment: This change can be overwritten anytime, it's generated automatically. If you read the comments at the top of that file, you can read: "Required method for Designer support - do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor."

Comment: Well, that's true. But you could also copy-paste the code in Form1.cs somewhere on top and it would still work :)